# Most efficient data structure for comparing and inserting

Tags: data-structures

So here is the circumstance I am facing: I have iterable objects called nodes. (approximately thousands) Each node contains many pairs of key and value. 
And my algorithm makes a new node (call it myNode) and checks each node in the iterable set, and 
 for each node in iterable set:
     for each pair(key,value) in node:
         if myNode contains the key of the pair:
             if myNode's corresponding value is bigger:
                 replaces with the new value.
         else: myNode.put(key, value)

Currently, I am using HashMap for this and it's pretty slow and I actually got better results after replacing the HashMap with ArrayList, which is very strange.
Can someone suggest better data structure to use to increase the performance of my program??

Thank you !

EDI: CODE

```
        ArrayList<Long> newDist = new ArrayList<Long>();

        HashMap<Long, Long> myNode = new HashMap<Long, Long>();

        for (Node i : nodes){//copy neighbors to set
            Set<Long> view = i.keySet();
            for (Long j : view) {
                if (!(myNode.containsKey(j))) {
                    myNode.put(j, i.get(j));
                } else if (myNode.get(j) > i.get(j)) {
                    myNode.put(j, i.get(j));
                }
            }
        }

        context.write(key, myNode);
```

Comment: Can you post your actual code, because HashMap very likely should be the best option.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what your codes intent is, because it references some objects you haven't included, but if `Node` is a `Map` then I would do something like....

```
Map<Long, Long> lowScores = new HashMap<Long, Long>();

for (Node node : nodes){
  for (Entry<Long,Long> entry : node.entrySet()) {
    Long lowScore = lowScores.get(entry.getKey());
    if (lowScore == null || lowScore > entry.getValue()){
      lowScores.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()); 
    }
  }
}
```

There are a few optimizations in here that limit the amount of operations that are done on the large data structures, but I only running will prove that that is optimizing things that the compiler wasn't already optimizing for you.  The key optimization is iterating over the `Entry` objects of the `Map` rather than keep calling `get` and `containsKey`.